# How can I import compiled C++ libraries into an Objective-C++ project in Xcode 4?

Tags: linker, static-libraries, objective-c++, skype

I'm trying to use the SkypeKit SDK to create an Objective-C++ project using Xcode 4. I have two compiled libraries from SkypeKit, libskypekit_cyassl_lib.a and libskypekit_cppwrapper_2_lib.a, which I need to be able to use so as to access the Skype API.

I've added in both .a files under 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' and added `-all_load -ObjC -lstdc++` to the 'Other Linker Flags', and that builds okay, but as soon as I try to use any of the methods in those libraries, building fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can call C++ code from Objective-C++, which means that your files should have the .mm extension instead of .m

I assume that this could be the issue, but since you did not specify the errors you get it is just a guess. Specifically, if you call C++ code from a .m file you get compilation errors.

Another possible cause is forgetting to import the header files of the library. For the import to be successful, you also have to add the directory where the headers are to your project "header search path".

If this does not help, please post the error message.

Comment: I am using .mm files, thanks.

In the C++ documentation for the SkypeKit API, there is:
`#include "skype-embedded_2.h"

#include "keypair.h"`


Including these lines results in 'file://...: error: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'skype-embedded_2.h' file not found'
If I don't include these header files, I instead get error messages about expecting a type, or types being invalid, though the only types I'm using are the most basic ones from the API.

Comment: you should try and add the directory where those files are to your project header search path. The message says that they cannot be found, so that will fix it.

Comment: could you find out where skype_embedded_2.h is located and add it to the search path? any improvements?

Comment: Nope, it's still not building. Might be time to get some sleep and have a look later ;)  
Thanks for your help anyway @sergio :)

Comment: So apparently trying it another time worked.  
Not sure what I did differently, but thanks :)